# Regular expressions get a single word out of a common phrase

Tags: regex

i have a phrase like this

*Computer, **Eddie** is gone to the market.*

I want to get the word Eddie and ignore all of the other words since other words are constant, and the word Eddie could be anything.

How can I do this in regular expression?

#### Edit:

Sorry I'm using .NET regex :)

Comment: This can be done by taking the position of "," and "is" and extracting the substring in between right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What language you're regex-ing in? Always specify this to get the most helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^Computer, \b(.+)\b is gone to the market\.$/
```

`Eddie` would be in the first captured string `$1`. If you specify the language, we can tell you how to extract it.

Edit: C#:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^Computer, \b(.+)\b is gone to the market\.$");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Get rid of `^` and `$` from the regex if the string would be part of another string - they match start and end of a line respectively.

Comment: It should be noted that this can capture `James Bond`, which isn't a "single word". The lesson here is that OP should've been more specific what is to be matched and captured.

Comment: @polygene OP said word Eddie could be anything; I took the liberty to assume it can be James Bond too :)

Comment: yep, it could also be James Bond, it could be a phrase a word or a letter or a number, anything could be as long as the other words are the same.

Comment: @rob: then perhaps though not ideal, `(.+)` or `(.+?)` is acceptable (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532 -- specifically the `A-Z` and `A-ZZ` examples).

Answer (score 6):

You can use this pattern:

```
Computer, (\w+) is gone to the market\.
```

This uses brackets to match `\w+` and captures it in group 1.

Note that the period at the end has been escaped with a `\` because `.` is a regex metacharacter.

Given the input:

```
LOL! Computer, Eddie is gone to the market. Blah blah
blah. Computer, Alice is gone to the market... perhaps...

Computer, James Bond is gone to the market.
```

Then there are two matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/XTjxMbYA5O)). In the first match, group 1 captured `Eddie`. In the second match, group 1 captured `Alice`.

Note that `\w+` doesn't match `James Bond`, because `\w+` is a sequence of "one or more word character". If you need to match these kinds non-"single word" names, then simply replace it with the regex to match the names.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Capturing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [The Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

---

#### General technique

Given this test string:

```
i have 35 dogs, 16 cats and 10 elephants
```

Then `(\d+) (cats|dogs)` yields 2 match results ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/b4AIq5CxQP))

- Result 1: `35 dogs`

  - Group 1 captures `35`
  - Group 2 captures `dogs`
- Result 2: `16 cats`

  - Group 1 captures `16`
  - Group 2 captures `cats`

#### Related questions

- [Saving substrings using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010684/saving-substrings-using-regular-expressions)

---

#### C# snippet

Here's a simple example of capturing groups usage:

```
var text = @"

LOL! Computer, Eddie is gone to the market. Blah blah
blah. Computer, Alice is gone to the market... perhaps...

Computer, James Bond is gone to the market.

";

Regex r = new Regex(@"Computer, (\w+) is gone to the market\.");

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text)) {
  Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

The above prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/MabAM)):

```
Eddie
Alice
```

#### API references

- [`System.Text.RegularExpressions` Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e.aspx)

---

#### On specification

As noted, `\w+` does not match `"James Bond"`. It does, however, match `"o_o"`, `"giggles2000"`, etc ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/bp9oqafyrj)). As much as reasonably practical, you should try to make your patterns as specific as possible.

Similarly, `(\d+) (cats|dogs)` will match `100 cats` in `$100 catsup` ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/e0gKCEbqec)).

These are issues on the patterns themselves, and not directly related to capturing groups.

Comment: +2 for explaining further about regex, really helps a lot.. :)